# Publishing option is not available for one content type

Tags: 6, nodes

I have drupal 6.25. I have some content types like article, editors, slideshow and others.
publishing options are listed normally for all content types except "article" (although i gave "administer nodes" permission to my editors). i have tried some modules like [Override Node Options](http://drupal.org/project/override_node_options) but i still have the same problem for this content type for all users (of course except the admin user, admin can see it normally).
any idea of what might cause this and how to fix it?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you check the HTML for the page ? Are the options in the code or did they disappear entirely ?

Comment: thanks @Countzero i fixed it already, and below is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed it already.
I found a form_alter hook in one of my modules. and in this hook there was the line below (i just commented it)

```
$form['options']['#attributes'] = array('style' => 'display:none');
```